# How to prove the det(A+bk) is an affine function of k

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Hey I was given a problem on a proof and I'm not sure how to approach it or solve it.

The statement was:

Show that for any row vector k $\in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$, any matrix A $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and any vector b $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ that det(A+bk) is an affine function of k, that is $$|A+bk| = d_0 + \sum_{i = 1}^n k_id_i$$ where k = $[k_1 ... k_n]$ and the $d_is$ are real numbers.

1. First prove this assuming A is invertible.
2. Show that when A is not invertible there exists a $\eta > 0$ small enough such that $\forall \epsilon (0,\eta], A+\epsilon I$ is invertible.
3. Prove the result for any A and b.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why don't you construct $A + bk$ with arbitrary indices $a_{i}, b_{i}, k_{i}$ up to some arbitrary $n$, then take the determinant to see what happens?

Comment: Show us your work first, please.